# Implementing a Parameterized Interface

Tags: java, generics

Given this interface:

```
import com.google.common.base.Optional;

public interface Foo<S extends Bar> {
  Optional<S> get();    
}
```

Then I've implemented the interface with `Foo`:

```
public class Baz implements Foo {
   public Optional<Bippie> get { ... }; // Bippie extends Bar
{
```

Is it necessary to put parameters on `class Baz`? Why or why not?

Comment: Should probably be `implements Foo<Bippie>`. Follow your IDE's guidance.

Comment: makes it parametrized that's what it's designed by you. If you don't want to use generic they why are you making the interface generic. First read why use generic? What is benefit of using Generic?

Comment: It might help you to understand it directly from the official Oracle document on [Generic Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/types.html).

Comment: **Generics** add stability to your code by making more of your **bugs detectable at compile time**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is technically legal to leave `Baz` as it is, implementing the raw `Foo` interface.  Java will treat all generics as if they don't exist, and that code will compile.

It's generally a bad idea to use raw types, however, and it's easy to implement the generic interface properly, so just do that.  You don't have to provide a generic type parameter on the class `Baz`:

```
public class Baz implements Foo<Bippie> {
    public Optional<Bippie> get() {
```

But you can if you want to:

```
public class Baz<S extends Bar> implements Foo<S> {
    public Optional<S> get() {
```

Or you could use `Bippie` to narrow it further:

```
public class Baz<S extends Bippie> implements Foo<S> {
    public Optional<S> get() {
```

Comment: in the first part of your answer: `public class Baz implements Foo<Bippie> {`, will `Baz#get()` return the `Bippie` type only? Or will `Bar` be an acceptable return type since `public interface Foo<S extends Bar> { Optional<S> get() ... }`?

Comment: It would have to be an `Optional<Bippie>`, because `Baz` is defining the `S` from `Foo` to be `Bippie`.

Comment: Ah, so when implementing the `Foo` interface, `Foo`'s type parameter **must be** a sub-type of `Bar`?

Comment: It could be a subtype of `Bar` or it could be `Bar` itself.

Comment: I'm confused: `(The use of the keyword extends is slightly misleading: recall from Item 26 that subtype is defined so that every type is a subtype of itself, even though it does not extend itself.)` **-Effective Java** (page 134 in my Kindle)

Comment: Yes, `extends` for wildcard bounds has a different meaning than for subclassing a class.  For wildcard bounds, `extends` means "is this type, or a subtype", and it applies to interfaces as well, e.g. `<T extends Runnable>` is possible.

Comment: Ah, the `interface Foo` in my above code is a `bounded type parameter`. So that's why in `Foo<S extends Bar>`, then `S` can be of type `Bar` or a sub-type.